# I'm bored. Do you like eating bananas? They make a good breakfast

Tags: riddle, rhyme, lateral-thinking, knowledge, video-games

> So for today, our riddle is broken into two. Can you figure out all of these clues?
>
> Am I the Alpha, the origin, the prime?
> I'm maybe victory, or part of a dime.
>
> Take one to the face, you will be in some pain,
> As it's in your stomach, tipsiness, you'll gain.
> Maybe you have seen it, found with Hawaii,
> A Shoryuken? Don't be a wannabe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how this relates to video games, but ...

> One Punch (Man)

Am I the Alpha, the origin, the prime?

> One = first = alpha = origin = prime

I'm maybe victory, or part of a dime.

> When you place first, you gain victory.
>  A dime includes ten ones.

Take one to the face, you will be in some pain,

> Punches to the face hurt.

As it's in your stomach, tipsiness, you'll gain.

> Alcoholic punch (a drink) can make you tipsy.

Maybe you have seen it, found with Hawaii,

> Hawaiian Punch is a brand of drink.

A Shoryuken? Don't be a wannabe.

> Shoryuken is an uppercut punch. (Which I only know because of Street Fighter. So... video games?)

Do you like eating bananas? They make a good breakfast

> One Punch Man has a rule about eating breakfast, for which a banana is fine.

---

Bonus: @Ertai87 points out

> The first letter of each line of your riddle spells One Punch Man's name: Saitama.

Comment: I included the video game tag because of that last hint. You'd have to know what a Shoryuken is to understand the riddle. You got the answer right; however, there is another hint found in the puzzle, can you find it?

Comment: rot13(gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu yvar fcryyf fnvgnzn)